# CSS and JS Files not rendering

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

My site has been up and running for several weeks now. However, all of a sudden, when i view my site, none of my CSS or JS files are rendering, in any browser.

I've used both drag and drop (in visual studio 2013) to put the respective files in the head and body, and also used the ResolveUrl method, to no avail.

Screen shot below shows that the respective files are loaded, but not rendered.

[image: Files downloading fine.]

[image: Network Errors]

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with iisExpress

This has me stumped

*** EDIT ***

Ok, so it looks like IISExpress is the culprit (locally). Switching to ISS shows all CSS and JS Files. Odd

Comment: You've got a 500 error, not a 404. The files are probably there but IISExpress is fooked. You're going to have to troubleshoot IISExpress not your app.

Comment: 500 is an internal server error.  Check event viewer to see if there is an error message.

Comment: You right RobH - switching to full blown IIS worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can only be resolved by fixes to the Web server software.

It is not a client-side problem. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse the logs which should give further information about the error.

**[Follow this link](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html)**

Comment: Vivek, this is all running locally, i have the source and it's the same locally as deployed.